# Finding context-sensitive grammar for a given language

Tags: formal-grammar

I was wondering, [in my other topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312916/find-grammar-for-given-language), how to find grammar for: $\left\{ a^n b^n c^n: n\ge 1 \right\}$ when I found [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples). Context-sensitive grammars is completely new topic for me and I don't understand few things.

Firstly: why is it OK? I think I get basic intuition behind this approach - we generate as many $a$ as we need and simultaneously same number of $B, \ C$ - space for the letters $b, \ c$. Then we use some kind of bubble sort to swap all adjacent $CB$ to get string in form: $a...aB...BC...C$ then we will easily get desired string using few steps.

But why can't we just use simply rule $CB\rightarrow BC$ and we need to do this transformation in few steps using nonterminal $H$?

Second question: is order of rules in context-sensitive grammars relevant? Because when we use this grammar like that: 
$$S\rightarrow aSBC\rightarrow aaBCBC\rightarrow aabCBC\rightarrow aabcBC$$ then we are in dead end, but I suppose I don't understand something and everything is OK. But why? Can you explain it to me? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of $H$ is there to force you to finish swapping the $B$s and $C$s before converting them to $b$s and $c$s. Otherwise, you could easily generate $aabcbc$, for example.

As for the second part, yes the order of *application* of rules in a context sensitive grammar is important, because one rule application may use up part of the string that another rule might otherwise use.

Comment: That explains a lot. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the "dead end", it means there are no rules to be applied, so the "calculation" (in terms of automata) ends. But the string cannot be accepted, since there are some non-terminals.